# Back to back game tying and game winning walk off home run

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb, home-run

Justin Smoke and Kendrys Morals of Toronto Blue Jays hit back to back home runs in the 9th inning against the Oakland Athletics on July 26 2017. Smoke's HR tied the game, and on the next pitch Morals hit a walk off home run to complete the comeback.

How many times in the history of the MLB a team won on a back to back game tying and game winning home runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have play by play data going back only to 1952, so this also an incomplete answer, but there have been 30 such incidences of back-to-back home runs, one tying the game, and one winning the game for teams in that time frame.

Here's a sampling from this decade:

- July 26, 2017 - Blue Jays, Smoak/Morales
- August 26, 2016 - Astros, Correa/Gattis
- August 19, 2016 - Indians, Ramirez/Naquin (Naquin hit an inside-the-parkwalk-off home-run!)
- June 18, 2014 - Red Sox, Ortiz/Napoli
- May 19, 2013 - Phillies, Kratz/Galvis (both came off of Aroldis Chapman, one of only two multiple-HR-appearances by Chapman. The other came in 2016 against the Twins)
- May 7, 2013 - Reds, Mesoraco/Choo     (both off of Craig Kimbrel - the *only* multiple-HR-appearance in Kimbrel's career)
- September 15, 2012 - Royals, Butler/Perez

Edit: Now, we have Christian Yelich/Ryan Braun for the Brewers on April 3, 2018!

Source: Retrosheet data - [retrosheet.org](http://www.retrosheet.org/).

Comment: Retrosheet data - http://www.retrosheet.org/