# Home runs on back to back pitches

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb, home-run

Related to [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16630/back-to-back-game-tying-and-game-winning-walk-off-home-run), I'm wondering how many times in MLB history a team has hit home runs on consecutive pitches. That is 2, 3, or 4 home runs in as many pitches.

Please provide the team, date and players hitting the homers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[On September 18th, 2006, J.D. Drew, Russell Martin, and Marlon Anderson hit home runs on 3 consecutive pitches](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/LAN/LAN200609180.shtml). Drew hit a home run off Jon Adkins. Martin and Anderson hit home runs off Trevor Hoffman.

I checked all of the instances of teams hitting 4 consecutive home runs, and this was the only one I found in which 3 were hit on consecutive pitches. However, there were 3 instances in the 1960's that didn't have pitch count available.

It's very likely that 3 is the record.

Comment: Tied by the Yankees in the 4th inning against the Blue Jays on September 17, 2020 by Brett Gardner (5th of the season), DJ LeMahieu (10th) and Luke Voit (20th) on consecutive pitches. In addition, Giancarlo Stanton (4th) and Gleyber Torres (3rd) also hit dingers for a total of 5 home runs (7 total runs) in the inning. The 5 home runs in an inning also ties a major league record.

Answer (score 2):

Tied by the Los Angeles Angels, against the Colorado Rockies, on June 24, 2023.

In the third inning, Mike Trout homered on a 1-0 count, followed by Brandon Drury and Matt Thais both homering on the first pitch.

Chase Anderson was the pitcher.  He was also the pitcher who allowed three home runs on consecutive pitches by the New York Yankees, when pitching for the Blue Jays, on September 17, 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Tied by the Yankees in the 4th inning against the Blue Jays on September 17, 2020 by Brett Gardner (5th of the season), DJ LeMahieu (10th) and Luke Voit (20th) on consecutive pitches. In addition, Giancarlo Stanton (4th) and Gleyber Torres (3rd) also hit dingers for a total of 5 home runs (7 total runs) in the inning. The 5 home runs in an inning also ties a major league record.

Answer (score 1):

Tied by the Cincinnati Reds, on May 5, 2019.

In the first inning, Eugenio Suarez, Jesse Winker, and Derek Dietrich all homered off Jeff Samardzija, of the San Francisco Giants.